# How to distinguish the terms 'primitives' 'axioms' 'expressions' 'basic axioms' 'primitive terms' in description logic / OWL?

Tags: logic, owl, rdfs, first-order-logic, description-logic

I have read several terms in the context of description logic / OWL Web Ontology Language, but it is hard for me to distinguish them. I could not find for any of them a clear definition in the context of the others, and authors use them often without clear definitions. Can someone help me?

The terms are in description logic / OWL:

- 'primitives'
- 'axioms'
- 'facts'
- 'expressions'
- 'basic axioms'
- 'complex axioms'
- 'primitive terms'
- 'triple'
- 'class description'
- 'class constructors'
- 'assertion' / 'asserted'

If someone could provide an example then distinguish them or show similarities between, would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **[axiom](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Axioms)** is any thing you know to be true in your domain, e.g. the fact that all the dogs are animals.

A particular kind of axiom is the **[assertion](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Assertions)** (or **fact**), which declares something about specific individuals (e.g. `Dog(lessie)` or `Parent(bob,alice)`).

A **[triple](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-primer/#section-triple)** is a particular way of storing a statements (e.g. `<ex:lessie rdf:type ex:Dog>`, or `<ex:bob Parent ex:alice>`, or `<ex:Dog rdfs:subclassof ex:Animal>`).

The **primitive terms** are the entities, such as classes, properties, and individuals.

A **primitive** is a particular function used for building [class expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Class_Expressions).

Anyway, some terms (like the adjectives "basic" and "complex") may have different meanings depending on the particular context.

Comment: A few extras, in the hope of clarifying further: triple refers to how an ontology can be written to a file in RDF format. Often an axiom or an assertion can be written with one triple (the examples given here are of that kind); other axioms/assertions cannot, and some syntaxes do not use triples at all (functional syntax for example). The semantics of an ontology does not depend on it, it's a syntactic construct.

Comment: class description - I've only met this as 'class definition', i.e., given a class name (a primitive term, or an IRI), there's an axiom that says the name is equivalent or included in another class name or class expression. A class expression is a class without a name, built using class constructors, such as union or intersection. Same for properties and properties expressions.

Comment: And yes, basic or complex can be pretty subjective terms. Possibly used for class definitions where the first term is not a primitive term but a class expression, also known as a general inclusion axiom, or GCI?